# Attempting to send local base64 image to server from localStorage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have a localStorage which i can create an image on the canvas, choose save and it stores the data/url into my localStorage. My question is... how do I send that url or decode it into a blob type to be able to display it in a php page?

I am using ajax and I want to attach it when my formdata is sent. I guess my main issue is trying to figure out the ajax request. Any help with this would be great.

My form sends great but my localstorage item is missing and doesnt get posted to the server.

my ajax

```
               $('#252whole').submit(function(event){

               var fd = new FormData( $(this)[0] );
               var img = localStorage.getItem('signature');

               $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   processData: false,
                   contentType: false,
                   async: false,
                   data: fd,img,
                   url: 'http://urltomyservice.php',
               success: function(data){
                alert('Form Submitted...');
                   },
               error: function(){
                        alert('There was an error converting the pdf!');
                   }
                    });
               return false;
                    }); 
               });
```

Comment: if the image is in base64 you want to encode it cause it probably has characters that urls do not except (if i'm reding your problem right). Try using encodeURIComponent(img)

Comment: first, you should change this line of your ajax to `data: {fd,img},` otherwise you won't submit both.

Comment: i get an error with data: {fd,img}, @blex

Comment: Whoops, sorry, needs to be `data: {fd:fd,img:img},`. If you still get an error, could you tell us what it is?

Comment: Ok thats a little better. I get no error... on either the client or the server side. Looking at the resources in my console, i don't even see the data/url being sent.

Comment: So you receive no alert()?

Comment: No. nothing... no alert or error in the console.